# Передача массива через socket python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x, сокет, сериализация, десериализация, pickle

Здравствуйте, нужно передать массив через сокет

**Код сервера**:

```
import socket
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1",10001))
sock.listen(socket.SOMAXCONN)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(4096)

    print(data)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

**Код клиента:**

```
import socket
import pickle

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1",10001))
arr = ('hello','world')
data_string = pickle.dumps(arr)
sock.send(data_string)
data = sock.recv(4096)
data_arr = pickle.loads(data)
sock.close()
print ('Received', repr(data_arr))
```

В результате получаем это:

> Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 50436)
>
> b'\x80\x03X\x05\x00\x00\x00helloq\x00X\x05\x00\x00\x00worldq\x01\x86q\x02.'
>
> b''

Как полученные данные превратить обратно в массив?

Comment: Как я понимаю, это у вас серверная часть выводит. Делайте там `pickle.loads()` для принятых данных, так же как на клиенте это делаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Клиент** сериализует сложный объект через [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) и получившиеся байты отправляет на сервер.
**Сервер** получает байты от клиента, и выполняет десериализацию объекта.

### client.py

```
import socket
import pickle

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': [2, 3],
    'c': {
        'c1': 'abc',
    }
}
print('Send:', obj)

data = pickle.dumps(obj)
sock.sendall(data)

print('Close')
sock.close()
```

### server.py

```
import pickle
import socket


BUFFER_SIZE = 4096


sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)

print('Sock name: {}'.format(sock.getsockname()))

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('Connected:', addr)

    all_data = bytearray()

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data:
            break

        print('Recv: {}: {}'.format(len(data), data))
        all_data += data
    
    print('All data ({}): {}'.format(len(all_data), all_data))
    
    obj = pickle.loads(all_data)
    print('Obj:', obj)

    print('Close')
    conn.close()
```

### Результат:

- Клиент:

> ```
> Send: {'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3], 'c': {'c1': 'abc'}}
> Close
> ```

- Сервер:

> ```
> Sock name: ('0.0.0.0', 9090)
> Connected: ('127.0.0.1', 2602)
> Recv: 66: b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02]q\x03(K\x02K\x03eX\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x04}q\x05X\x02\x00\x00\x00c1q\x06X\x03\x00\x00\x00abcq\x07su.'
> All data (66): b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02]q\x03(K\x02K\x03eX\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x04}q\x05X\x02\x00\x00\x00c1q\x06X\x03\x00\x00\x00abcq\x07su.'
> Obj: {'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3], 'c': {'c1': 'abc'}}
> Close
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы передать объект через его сначала нужно преобразовать в JSON, а на клиенте спарсить полученную строку

Comment: Не обязательно в json. Можно и в байты сериализовать.